# getFirstElement of IStructuredSelection returns null

Tags: java, treeview, swt, jface, double-click

I have an Interface ITreeListener which has an abstract method doubleClick() and a class which implements this interface and overrides the doubleClick() method. doubleClick is being done on a Tree.

```
public class example implements ITreeListener {
TreeViewer viewer;
TreeListener treeListener = new TreeListener(viewer); //call constructor of another class (TreeListener)
treeListener.addListener(this);
@override
public void doubleClick() {
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();
Object item = ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();
}
```

In the above code getSelection() returns TreeSelection but getFirstElement() returns null.

I have another class(TreeListener) from where I call the doubleClick() method of the "example" class. TreeListener class implements IDoubleClickListener interface and overrides the method doubleClick() of IDoubleClickListener. The reason I have this kind of implementation is that I will have a common code in the doubleClick() method of TreeListener class wherein double clicking expands/collapses tree items and my own defined method doubleClick() of ITreeListener interface will have the code wherein double clicking tree items without any children will open the tree item for modifications of their name. Here's my TreeListener class :

```
public class TreeListener implements IDoubleClickListener {
final TreeViewer viewer;
ListenerList treeListeners = new ListenerList();

public TreeListener(TreeViewer viewer) {
    this.viewer = viewer;
    viewer.addDoubleClickListener(this);
}

public void addListener(ITreeListener treeListener) {
    treeListeners.add(treeListener);
    if (treeListeners != null) {
        Object[] listeners = treeListeners.getListeners();
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; ++i) {
        treeListener = (ITreeListener) listeners[i];
        treeListener.doubleClick(); \\calls doubleClick() method of example class               
        }
    }
}

// Expands/Collapses the tree item
@Override
public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
    //logic for expanding/collapsing tree items
}
```

In the above code if the call **treeListener.doubleClick();** is inside the overridden method doubleClick() such as:

```
    // Expands/Collapses the tree item
@Override
public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
    //logic for expanding/collapsing tree items
    treeListener.doubleClick(); \\this call works fine
}
```

But if the call **treeListener.doubleClick();** is inside the for loop of addListener method then the getFirstElement() of example class returns null. why is this happening? Do I have to notify the listeners inside addListener() method? If so How do I do that? Y is there a change in behavior if the call **treeListener.doubleClick();** is in another method? Can someone please suggest me on how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: `getFirstElement` returns null when there is no selection - so you are probably calling it before a selection has been made.

Comment: But the same call **treeListener.doubleClick();** works fine inside the overridden doubleClick() method of TreeListener class.

Comment: Yes when double click is called there will be a selection but when the tree is first created there is no selection.